# Receiving a error trying to list the table of database postgres TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql

I trying to list all inserts I made in the table of my db postgres,but i getting this error:

```
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received null 
    at prepareSecretKey (internal/crypto/keys.js:322:11)
    at new Hmac (internal/crypto/hash.js:111:9)
    at Object.createHmac (crypto.js:147:10)
    at hmacSha256 (C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\projeto-clinica\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:191:17)
    at Hi (C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\projeto-clinica\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:195:13)
    at Object.continueSession (C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\projeto-clinica\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:40:24)
    at Client._handleAuthSASLContinue (C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\projeto-clinica\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:257:10)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\projeto-clinica\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:114:12
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\projeto-clinica\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:40:17) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

This is my code for show the data:

```
const pool = new Pool();

exports.index = (req, res) => {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM medico ORDER BY nome";
    pool.query(sql, [], (err,result) => {
        if(err) {
            return console.error(err.message);
        }
        res.render('medico', { model: result.rows});
    });
}
```

Database connection

```
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'clinica-veterinaria',
    password: 'admin',
    port: 5432,
  })

  pool.connect();
```

Can't figure out whats its going on,password and username of database and all the other paramaters are all correct,but even with all set,I'm still getting this error

Comment: how do you configure the pg client with the database params?

Comment: const pool = new Pool({                          
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'clinica-veterinaria',
    password: 'admin',
    port: 5432,
  })

  pool.connect();

Comment: The issue seems to be here: `prepareSecretKey (internal/crypto/keys.js:322:11)` so something to do with `sasl`. This is going to need more information 1) Postgres version you are connecting to? 2) The Javascript driver/program and version you are using? 3) Are you using some other then straight password authentication to connect?